# ¿Cómo insertar variables globales dentro del DOM?

Tags: javascript

Intento insertar variables que sean globales dentro del DOM, es decir

```
var nombre = "valor";
```

Y los nombres de variables pueden ir así en el DOM

```
{{ nombre }}
```

Al momento de cargar la página `{{ nombre }}` debe ser reemplazando con `valor`, pues ese el valor de la variable

Al momento lo que he hecho es reemplazar las llaves con una etiqueta HTML e identificar la variable

```js
var hola = "hola mundo";

const h = document.querySelector("html");
h.innerHTML = h.innerHTML.replaceAll("{{", "<varstamp>").replaceAll("}}", "</varstamp>");

document.querySelectorAll("varstamp").forEach(el => {
  const req = el.innerHTML.replace(/\ /g, "");
  h.innerHTML = h.innerHTML.replace("<varstamp>"+el.innerHTML+"</varstamp>", window[req]);
});
```

```html
{{ hola }}
<p>{{hola}}</p>
<p>{{notDefined}}</p>
```

Al momento, funciona bien, pero el problema es que no funciona en atributos, es decir si un elemento tiene un atributo

```
<a attr="{{ hello }}">Link</a>
```

Resultaría `

```
<a attr="<varstamp> nombre </varstamp>">Link</a>
```

Y como es un elemento no iterable, no va a ser reemplazado

El objetivo es que funcione tanto dentro de elementos como en atributos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que funcione en atributos, te sugiero una opción más viable, minimizando el uso de expresiones regulares y simplificando la lógica:

1. Trabajar sobre una cadena para no sobrecargar al navegador renderizando en cada remplazo
2. Obtener primero todos los códigos a remplazar
3. Recorrer para obtener la variable y aplicar el remplazo

```js
var hola = "hola mundo";

const h = document.querySelector("html");
// Trabajar directamente sobre una cadena para que el navegador no renderice en cada iteración
let html = h.innerHTML;
// Obtener todos los códigos a remplazar
const matches = html.match(/{{(\w|\s)*}}/g);
// Recorrer para aplicar remplazos
matches.forEach(match => {
    // Obtener variable eliminando llaves en los extremos y posibles espacios
    let variable = match.substring(2, match.length - 2).trim();
    // Remplazar
    html = html.replaceAll(match, `<varstamp>${window[variable]}</varstamp>`);
});
// Ahora sí, actualizar HTML
h.innerHTML = html;

// Comprobar que funciona en atributos:
let p = document.querySelector('#funciona');
console.log(p);
```

```html
{{ hola }}
<p>{{hola}}</p>
<p>{{notDefined}}</p>
<p class="{{ hola }}" id="funciona">{{ noDefinida }}</p>
```